# Creating a custom user store manager in wso2 IS KM 5.7.0 not visible in the drop down of user stores in carbon screen

Tags: osgi, wso2, osgi-bundle, wso2-identity-server

I have a user table in my system with the columns USER_ID, PASSWORD, EMAIL, STATUS, etc. I wanted to incorporate the same user table in wso2 is 5.7.0, so I have created a custom user store extending JDBCUserStoreManager.I have followed this link:

http://pushpalankajaya.blogspot.com/2013/09/how-to-write-custom-user-store-manager.html.

I know that the tutorial is for older version of wso2 IS, so I have taken the pom file reference from this link:

https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS570/Writing+a+Custom+User+Store+Manager

Then I have successfully built a OSGI bundle in eclipse and uploaded it in the /repository/components/dropins directory. But still while starting the server with -DosgiConsole (To print the bundle activated logs), I do not see the bundle activated logs for my bundle. And also while trying to add new user store I do not see the CustomUserStoreManager in the drop down.

Am I missing anything here??? Any help would be highly appreciable.

My current pom.xml file:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>org.wso2.custom.user.store</groupId>
    <artifactId>org.wso2.custom.user.store.CustomUserStoreManager</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0</version>
    <packaging>bundle</packaging>
    
    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>wso2-nexus</id>
            <name>WSO2 internal Repository</name>
            <url>http://maven.wso2.org/nexus/content/groups/wso2-public/</url>
            <releases>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
                <updatePolicy>daily</updatePolicy>
                <checksumPolicy>ignore</checksumPolicy>
            </releases>
        </repository>
    </repositories>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.wso2.carbon</groupId>
            <artifactId>org.wso2.carbon.user.core</artifactId>
            <version>4.4.11</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.wso2.carbon</groupId>
            <artifactId>org.wso2.carbon.utils</artifactId>
            <version>4.4.11</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.wso2.carbon</groupId>
            <artifactId>org.wso2.carbon.user.api</artifactId>
            <version>4.4.11</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
    <plugins>
  <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.felix</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-bundle-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.3.5</version>
                <extensions>true</extensions>
                <configuration>
                    <instructions>
                        <Bundle-SymbolicName>${project.artifactId}</Bundle-SymbolicName>
                        <Bundle-Name>${project.artifactId}</Bundle-Name>
                        <Private-Package>
                            org.wso2.custom.user.store.internal
                        </Private-Package>
                        <Export-Package>
                            !org.wso2.custom.user.store.internal,
                            org.wso2.custom.user.store.*,
                        </Export-Package>
                        <Import-Package>
                            org.wso2.carbon.*,
                            org.apache.commons.logging.*,
                            org.osgi.framework.*,
                            org.osgi.service.component.*
                        </Import-Package>
                    </instructions>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>    
    </plugins>
    <pluginManagement>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.3.1</version>
                <inherited>true</inherited>
                <configuration>
                    <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
                    <source>1.7</source>
                    <target>1.7</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.felix</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-scr-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.7.2</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>generate-scr-scrdescriptor</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>scr</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
     </pluginManagement>
    </build>
</project>
```

Other java files:

```
package org.wso2.custom.user.store;
import org.apache.commons.logging.Log;
import org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory;
import org.wso2.carbon.CarbonConstants;
import org.wso2.carbon.user.api.Properties;
import org.wso2.carbon.user.api.Property;
import org.wso2.carbon.user.core.UserRealm;
import org.wso2.carbon.user.core.UserStoreException;
import org.wso2.carbon.user.core.claim.ClaimManager;
import org.wso2.carbon.user.core.jdbc.JDBCRealmConstants;
import org.wso2.carbon.user.core.jdbc.JDBCUserStoreManager;
import org.wso2.carbon.user.core.profile.ProfileConfigurationManager;
import org.wso2.carbon.user.core.util.DatabaseUtil;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Map;


/**
 * Sample User Store Manager Class
 * <p/>
 * This is a sample user store manage for a user table which contains columns -
 * customer_id, customer_name and password
 * <p/>
 * This has been extended the JDBCUserStoreManager class  which is shipped with carbon.user.core
 * bundle and override some methods.
 * <p/>
 * JDBCUserStoreManager can not be used for a user table with contains two columns. Therefore these
 * override method just ensure that reading is done according to the custom schema.
 * Therefore most of the override methods are same as the methods in JDBCUserStoreManager class.
 * <p/>
 * Some functionality has been limited this user table such as tenant aware, salted password
 * value ,creating time of user and etc.
 * <p/>
 * This class only a sample demonstration of writing a custom user store manager. Also anyone can
 * write their own implementation by extending AbstractUserStoreManager or implementing UserStoreManager
 */
public class CustomUserStoreManager extends JDBCUserStoreManager {


    private static Log log = LogFactory.getLog(CustomUserStoreManager.class);

    public CustomUserStoreManager() {
    }

    public CustomUserStoreManager(org.wso2.carbon.user.api.RealmConfiguration realmConfig,
                                  Map<String, Object> properties,
                                  ClaimManager claimManager,
                                  ProfileConfigurationManager profileManager,
                                  UserRealm realm, Integer tenantId)
            throws UserStoreException {
        super(realmConfig, properties, claimManager, profileManager, realm, tenantId, false);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean doAuthenticate(String userName, Object credential) throws UserStoreException {

        if (CarbonConstants.REGISTRY_ANONNYMOUS_USERNAME.equals(userName)) {
            log.error("Anonymous user trying to login");
            return false;
        }

        Connection dbConnection = null;
        ResultSet rs = null;
        PreparedStatement prepStmt = null;
        String sqlstmt = null;
        String password = (String) credential;
        boolean isAuthed = false;

        try {
            dbConnection = getDBConnection();
            dbConnection.setAutoCommit(false);
            //paring the SELECT_USER_SQL from user_mgt.xml
            sqlstmt = realmConfig.getUserStoreProperty(JDBCRealmConstants.SELECT_USER);

            if (log.isDebugEnabled()) {
                log.debug(sqlstmt);
            }

            prepStmt = dbConnection.prepareStatement(sqlstmt);
            prepStmt.setString(1, userName);

            rs = prepStmt.executeQuery();

            if (rs.next()) {
                String storedPassword = rs.getString(2);
                if ((storedPassword != null) && (storedPassword.trim().equals(password))) {
                    isAuthed = true;
                }

            }
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            throw new UserStoreException("Authentication Failure. Using sql :" + sqlstmt);
        } finally {
            DatabaseUtil.closeAllConnections(dbConnection, rs, prepStmt);
        }

        if (log.isDebugEnabled()) {
            log.debug("User " + userName + " login attempt. Login success :: " + isAuthed);
        }

        return isAuthed;

    }

    @Override
    public Date getPasswordExpirationTime(String userName) throws UserStoreException {
        return null;
    }

    protected boolean isValueExisting(String sqlStmt, Connection dbConnection, Object... params)
            throws UserStoreException {
        PreparedStatement prepStmt = null;
        ResultSet rs = null;
        boolean isExisting = false;
        boolean doClose = false;
        try {
            if (dbConnection == null) {
                dbConnection = getDBConnection();
                doClose = true; //because we created it
            }
            if (DatabaseUtil.getStringValuesFromDatabase(dbConnection, sqlStmt, params).length > 0) {
                isExisting = true;
            }
            return isExisting;
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            log.error(e.getMessage(), e);
            log.error("Using sql : " + sqlStmt);
            throw new UserStoreException(e.getMessage(), e);
        } finally {
            if (doClose) {
                DatabaseUtil.closeAllConnections(dbConnection, rs, prepStmt);
            }
        }
    }

    public String[] getUserListFromProperties(String property, String value, String profileName)
            throws UserStoreException {
        return new String[0];
    }


    /*@Override
    public Map<String, String> doGetUserClaimValues(String userName, String[] claims,
                                                    String domainName) throws UserStoreException {
        return new HashMap<String, String>();
    }*/

    /*@Override
    public String doGetUserClaimValue(String userName, String claim, String profileName)
            throws UserStoreException {
        return null;
    }*/

    @Override
    public boolean isReadOnly() throws UserStoreException {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void doAddUser(String userName, Object credential, String[] roleList,
                          Map<String, String> claims, String profileName,
                          boolean requirePasswordChange) throws UserStoreException {
        throw new UserStoreException(
                "User store is operating in read only mode. Cannot write into the user store.");
    }

    public void doAddRole(String roleName, String[] userList, org.wso2.carbon.user.api.Permission[] permissions)
            throws UserStoreException {
        throw new UserStoreException(
                "User store is operating in read only mode. Cannot write into the user store.");
    }

    @Override
    public void doDeleteRole(String roleName) throws UserStoreException {
        throw new UserStoreException(
                "User store is operating in read only mode. Cannot write into the user store.");
    }

    @Override
    public void doDeleteUser(String userName) throws UserStoreException {
        throw new UserStoreException(
                "User store is operating in read only mode. Cannot write into the user store.");
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isBulkImportSupported() {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public void doUpdateRoleName(String roleName, String newRoleName) throws UserStoreException {
        throw new UserStoreException(
                "User store is operating in read only mode. Cannot write into the user store.");
    }

    @Override
    public void doUpdateUserListOfRole(String roleName, String[] deletedUsers, String[] newUsers)
            throws UserStoreException {
        throw new UserStoreException(
                "User store is operating in read only mode. Cannot write into the user store.");
    }

    @Override
    public void doUpdateRoleListOfUser(String userName, String[] deletedRoles, String[] newRoles)
            throws UserStoreException {
        throw new UserStoreException(
                "User store is operating in read only mode. Cannot write into the user store.");
    }

    @Override
    public void doSetUserClaimValue(String userName, String claimURI, String claimValue,
                                    String profileName) throws UserStoreException {
        throw new UserStoreException(
                "User store is operating in read only mode. Cannot write into the user store.");
    }

    @Override
    public void doSetUserClaimValues(String userName, Map<String, String> claims,
                                     String profileName) throws UserStoreException {
        throw new UserStoreException(
                "User store is operating in read only mode. Cannot write into the user store.");
    }

    @Override
    public void doDeleteUserClaimValue(String userName, String claimURI, String profileName)
            throws UserStoreException {
        throw new UserStoreException(
                "User store is operating in read only mode. Cannot write into the user store.");
    }

    @Override
    public void doDeleteUserClaimValues(String userName, String[] claims, String profileName)
            throws UserStoreException {
        throw new UserStoreException(
                "User store is operating in read only mode. Cannot write into the user store.");
    }

    @Override
    public void doUpdateCredential(String userName, Object newCredential, Object oldCredential)
            throws UserStoreException {
        throw new UserStoreException(
                "User store is operating in read only mode. Cannot write into the user store.");
    }

    @Override
    public void doUpdateCredentialByAdmin(String userName, Object newCredential)
            throws UserStoreException {
        throw new UserStoreException(
                "User store is operating in read only mode. Cannot write into the user store.");
    }

    public String[] getExternalRoleListOfUser(String userName) throws UserStoreException {
        /*informix user store manager is supposed to be read only and users in the custom user store
          users in the custom user store are only assigned to internal roles. Therefore this method
          returns an empty string.
         */

        return new String[0];
    }

    @Override
    public String[] doGetRoleNames(String filter, int maxItemLimit) throws UserStoreException {
        return new String[0];
    }

    @Override
    public boolean doCheckExistingRole(String roleName) throws UserStoreException {

        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean doCheckExistingUser(String userName) throws UserStoreException {

        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public org.wso2.carbon.user.api.Properties getDefaultUserStoreProperties(){
        Properties properties = new Properties();
        properties.setMandatoryProperties(CustomUserStoreConstants.CUSTOM_UM_MANDATORY_PROPERTIES.toArray
                (new Property[CustomUserStoreConstants.CUSTOM_UM_MANDATORY_PROPERTIES.size()]));
        properties.setOptionalProperties(CustomUserStoreConstants.CUSTOM_UM_OPTIONAL_PROPERTIES.toArray
                (new Property[CustomUserStoreConstants.CUSTOM_UM_OPTIONAL_PROPERTIES.size()]));
        properties.setAdvancedProperties(CustomUserStoreConstants.CUSTOM_UM_ADVANCED_PROPERTIES.toArray
                (new Property[CustomUserStoreConstants.CUSTOM_UM_ADVANCED_PROPERTIES.size()]));
        return properties;
    }
}

    /*
 * Copyright 2005-2007 WSO2, Inc. (http://wso2.com)
 *
 * Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
 * you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
 * You may obtain a copy of the License at
 *
 * http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
 *
 * Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
 * distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
 * WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
 * See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
 * limitations under the License.
 */
package org.wso2.custom.user.store;


import org.wso2.carbon.user.api.Property;
import org.wso2.carbon.user.core.UserStoreConfigConstants;
import org.wso2.carbon.user.core.jdbc.JDBCRealmConstants;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class CustomUserStoreConstants {


    //Properties for Read Active Directory User Store Manager
    public static final ArrayList<Property> CUSTOM_UM_MANDATORY_PROPERTIES = new ArrayList<Property>();
    public static final ArrayList<Property> CUSTOM_UM_OPTIONAL_PROPERTIES = new ArrayList<Property>();
    public static final ArrayList<Property> CUSTOM_UM_ADVANCED_PROPERTIES = new ArrayList<Property>();


    static {

        setMandatoryProperty(JDBCRealmConstants.DRIVER_NAME, "oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver", "Full qualified driver name");
        setMandatoryProperty(JDBCRealmConstants.URL, "", "URL of the user store database");
        setMandatoryProperty(JDBCRealmConstants.USER_NAME, "", "Username for the database");
        setMandatoryProperty(JDBCRealmConstants.PASSWORD, "", "Password for the database");

        setProperty(UserStoreConfigConstants.disabled, "false", UserStoreConfigConstants.disabledDescription);

        setProperty("ReadOnly", "true", "Indicates whether the user store of this realm operates in the user read only mode or not");
        setProperty(UserStoreConfigConstants.SCIMEnabled, "false", UserStoreConfigConstants.SCIMEnabledDescription);


        //Advanced Properties (No descriptions added for each property)
        setAdvancedProperty("SelectUserSQL", "SELECT * FROM USER_MASTER WHERE USER_ID=?", "");
        setAdvancedProperty("UserFilterSQL", "SELECT USER_ID FROM USER_MASTER WHERE USER_ID LIKE ?  ORDER BY USER_ID", "");

    }


    private static void setProperty(String name, String value, String description) {
        Property property = new Property(name, value, description, null);
        CUSTOM_UM_OPTIONAL_PROPERTIES.add(property);

    }

    private static void setMandatoryProperty(String name, String value, String description) {
        Property property = new Property(name, value, description, null);
        CUSTOM_UM_MANDATORY_PROPERTIES.add(property);

    }

    private static void setAdvancedProperty(String name, String value, String description) {
        Property property = new Property(name, value, description, null);
        CUSTOM_UM_ADVANCED_PROPERTIES.add(property);

    }


}

package org.wso2.custom.user.store.internal;
import org.apache.commons.logging.Log;
import org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory;
import org.osgi.service.component.ComponentContext;
import org.wso2.carbon.user.core.service.RealmService;
import org.wso2.custom.user.store.CustomUserStoreManager;
import org.wso2.carbon.user.api.UserStoreManager;


/**
 * @scr.component name="custom.user.store.manager.dscomponent" immediate=true
 * @scr.reference name="user.realmservice.default"
 * interface="org.wso2.carbon.user.core.service.RealmService"
 * cardinality="1..1" policy="dynamic" bind="setRealmService"
 * unbind="unsetRealmService"
 */
public class CustomUserStoreMgtDSComponent {
    private static Log log = LogFactory.getLog(CustomUserStoreMgtDSComponent.class);
    private static RealmService realmService;

    protected void activate(ComponentContext ctxt) {

        CustomUserStoreManager customUserStoreManager = new CustomUserStoreManager();
        ctxt.getBundleContext().registerService(UserStoreManager.class.getName(), customUserStoreManager, null);
        log.info("CustomUserStoreManager bundle activated successfully..");
    }

    protected void deactivate(ComponentContext ctxt) {
        if (log.isDebugEnabled()) {
            log.debug("CustomUserStoreManager is deactivated ");
        }
    }

    protected void setRealmService(RealmService rlmService) {
          realmService = rlmService;
    }

    protected void unsetRealmService(RealmService realmService) {
        realmService = null;
    }

    public static RealmService getRealmService() {
        return realmService;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, it worked. Thanks for guiding me. I have referred the below link and made changes to my code:

https://github.com/wso2/product-is/tree/master/modules/samples/user-mgt/sample-custom-user-store-manager

As there is not updated tutorial/sample to follow, I would like to post my updated code here:

pom.xml file:

```js
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">

    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <version>1.0</version>
    <packaging>bundle</packaging>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
      <groupId>org.wso2.carbon</groupId>
      <artifactId>org.wso2.carbon.user.core</artifactId>
      <version>4.4.35</version>
  </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.wso2.carbon</groupId>
            <artifactId>org.wso2.carbon.user.api</artifactId>
            <version>4.4.35</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.felix</groupId>
            <artifactId>org.apache.felix.scr.ds-annotations</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
            <version>1.2.10</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.7</source>
                    <target>1.7</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.felix</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-bundle-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.2.0</version>
                <extensions>true</extensions>
                <configuration>
                    <instructions>
                        <Bundle-SymbolicName>${pom.artifactId}</Bundle-SymbolicName>
                        <Bundle-Name>${pom.artifactId}</Bundle-Name>
                        <Private-Package>
                            org.wso2.sample.user.store.manager.internal
                        </Private-Package>
                        <Export-Package>
                            !org.wso2.sample.user.store.manager.internal,
                            org.wso2.sample.user.store.manager.*,
                        </Export-Package>
                        <Import-Package>
                            javax.servlet; version=2.4.0,
                            javax.servlet.http; version=2.4.0,
                            org.wso2.carbon.base.*,
                            org.wso2.carbon.user.core.*,
                            <!--                            org.apache.lucene.*,-->
                            *;resolution:=optional
                        </Import-Package>
                        <DynamicImport-Package>*</DynamicImport-Package>
                    </instructions>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
    <groupId>org.wso2.sample.user.store.manager</groupId>
    <artifactId>CustomJDBCUserStoreManager</artifactId>
</project>
```

And the java files:

JDBCUserStoreManager.java:

```
package org.wso2.sample.user.store.manager;

import org.apache.commons.logging.Log;
import org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory;
import org.wso2.carbon.CarbonConstants;
import org.wso2.carbon.user.api.*;
import org.wso2.carbon.user.core.UserRealm;
import org.wso2.carbon.user.core.UserStoreException;
import org.wso2.carbon.user.core.claim.ClaimManager;
import org.wso2.carbon.user.core.jdbc.JDBCRealmConstants;
import org.wso2.carbon.user.core.profile.ProfileConfigurationManager;
import org.wso2.carbon.user.core.util.DatabaseUtil;


import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Map;


/**
 * Sample User Store Manager Class
 */
public class CustomJDBCUserStoreManager extends org.wso2.carbon.user.core.jdbc.JDBCUserStoreManager {

     private static Log log = LogFactory.getLog(CustomJDBCUserStoreManager.class);

    public CustomJDBCUserStoreManager() {

    }

    public CustomJDBCUserStoreManager(org.wso2.carbon.user.api.RealmConfiguration realmConfig,
            Map<String, Object> properties,
            ClaimManager claimManager,
            ProfileConfigurationManager profileManager,
            UserRealm realm, Integer tenantId)
                    throws UserStoreException {
        super(realmConfig, properties, claimManager, profileManager, realm, tenantId, false);
        }

    @Override
    public boolean doAuthenticate(String userName, Object credential) throws UserStoreException {

        log.info("CustomUserStoreManager:: doAuthenticate:: Entry");

        if (CarbonConstants.REGISTRY_ANONNYMOUS_USERNAME.equals(userName)) {
            log.error("Anonymous user trying to login");
            return false;
        }

        Connection dbConnection = null;
        ResultSet rs = null;
        PreparedStatement prepStmt = null;
        String sqlstmt = null;
        String password = (String) credential;
        boolean isAuthed = false;

        try {
            dbConnection = getDBConnection();
            dbConnection.setAutoCommit(false);
            //paring the SELECT_USER_SQL from user_mgt.xml
            sqlstmt = realmConfig.getUserStoreProperty(JDBCRealmConstants.SELECT_USER);

            if (log.isDebugEnabled()) {
                log.debug(sqlstmt);
            }

            log.warn("SQL:: "+sqlstmt);
            log.warn("Username:: "+userName+"Password:: "+password);

            prepStmt = dbConnection.prepareStatement(sqlstmt);
            prepStmt.setString(1, userName);

            rs = prepStmt.executeQuery();

            if (rs.next()) {
                String storedPassword = rs.getString(2);
                log.warn("Stored Password:: "+storedPassword);
                if ((storedPassword != null) && (storedPassword.trim().equals(password))) {
                    isAuthed = true;
                }

            }
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            throw new UserStoreException("Authentication Failure. Using sql :" + sqlstmt);
        } finally {
            DatabaseUtil.closeAllConnections(dbConnection, rs, prepStmt);
        }

        if (log.isDebugEnabled()) {
            log.debug("User " + userName + " login attempt. Login success :: " + isAuthed);
        }
        log.info("CustomUserStoreManager:: doAuthenticate:: Exit isAuthed::"+isAuthed);
        return isAuthed;

    }

    @Override
    public Date getPasswordExpirationTime(String userName) throws UserStoreException {
        return null;
    }

    protected boolean isValueExisting(String sqlStmt, Connection dbConnection, Object... params)
            throws UserStoreException {
        PreparedStatement prepStmt = null;
        ResultSet rs = null;
        boolean isExisting = false;
        boolean doClose = false;
        try {
            if (dbConnection == null) {
                dbConnection = getDBConnection();
                doClose = true; //because we created it
            }
            if (DatabaseUtil.getStringValuesFromDatabase(dbConnection, sqlStmt, params).length > 0) {
                isExisting = true;
            }
            return isExisting;
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            log.error(e.getMessage(), e);
            log.error("Using sql : " + sqlStmt);
            throw new UserStoreException(e.getMessage(), e);
        } finally {
            if (doClose) {
                DatabaseUtil.closeAllConnections(dbConnection, rs, prepStmt);
            }
        }
    }

    public String[] getUserListFromProperties(String property, String value, String profileName)
            throws UserStoreException {
        return new String[0];
    }


    /*@Override
    public Map<String, String> doGetUserClaimValues(String userName, String[] claims,
                                                    String domainName) throws UserStoreException {
        return new HashMap<String, String>();
    }*/

    /*@Override
    public String doGetUserClaimValue(String userName, String claim, String profileName)
            throws UserStoreException {
        return null;
    }*/

    @Override
    public boolean isReadOnly() throws UserStoreException {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void doAddUser(String userName, Object credential, String[] roleList,
                          Map<String, String> claims, String profileName,
                          boolean requirePasswordChange) throws UserStoreException {
        throw new UserStoreException(
                "User store is operating in read only mode. Cannot write into the user store.");
    }

    public void doAddRole(String roleName, String[] userList, org.wso2.carbon.user.api.Permission[] permissions)
            throws UserStoreException {
        throw new UserStoreException(
                "User store is operating in read only mode. Cannot write into the user store.");
    }

    @Override
    public void doDeleteRole(String roleName) throws UserStoreException {
        throw new UserStoreException(
                "User store is operating in read only mode. Cannot write into the user store.");
    }

    @Override
    public void doDeleteUser(String userName) throws UserStoreException {
        throw new UserStoreException(
                "User store is operating in read only mode. Cannot write into the user store.");
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isBulkImportSupported() {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public void doUpdateRoleName(String roleName, String newRoleName) throws UserStoreException {
        throw new UserStoreException(
                "User store is operating in read only mode. Cannot write into the user store.");
    }

    @Override
    public void doUpdateUserListOfRole(String roleName, String[] deletedUsers, String[] newUsers)
            throws UserStoreException {
        throw new UserStoreException(
                "User store is operating in read only mode. Cannot write into the user store.");
    }

    @Override
    public void doUpdateRoleListOfUser(String userName, String[] deletedRoles, String[] newRoles)
            throws UserStoreException {
        throw new UserStoreException(
                "User store is operating in read only mode. Cannot write into the user store.");
    }

    @Override
    public void doSetUserClaimValue(String userName, String claimURI, String claimValue,
                                    String profileName) throws UserStoreException {
        throw new UserStoreException(
                "User store is operating in read only mode. Cannot write into the user store.");
    }

    @Override
    public void doSetUserClaimValues(String userName, Map<String, String> claims,
                                     String profileName) throws UserStoreException {
        throw new UserStoreException(
                "User store is operating in read only mode. Cannot write into the user store.");
    }

    @Override
    public void doDeleteUserClaimValue(String userName, String claimURI, String profileName)
            throws UserStoreException {
        throw new UserStoreException(
                "User store is operating in read only mode. Cannot write into the user store.");
    }

    @Override
    public void doDeleteUserClaimValues(String userName, String[] claims, String profileName)
            throws UserStoreException {
        throw new UserStoreException(
                "User store is operating in read only mode. Cannot write into the user store.");
    }

    @Override
    public void doUpdateCredential(String userName, Object newCredential, Object oldCredential)
            throws UserStoreException {
        throw new UserStoreException(
                "User store is operating in read only mode. Cannot write into the user store.");
    }

    @Override
    public void doUpdateCredentialByAdmin(String userName, Object newCredential)
            throws UserStoreException {
        throw new UserStoreException(
                "User store is operating in read only mode. Cannot write into the user store.");
    }

    public String[] getExternalRoleListOfUser(String userName) throws UserStoreException {
        /*informix user store manager is supposed to be read only and users in the custom user store
          users in the custom user store are only assigned to internal roles. Therefore this method
          returns an empty string.
         */

        return new String[0];
    }

    @Override
    public String[] doGetRoleNames(String filter, int maxItemLimit) throws UserStoreException {
        return new String[0];
    }

    @Override
    public boolean doCheckExistingRole(String roleName) throws UserStoreException {

        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean doCheckExistingUser(String userName) throws UserStoreException {

        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public org.wso2.carbon.user.api.Properties getDefaultUserStoreProperties(){
        Properties properties = new Properties();
        properties.setMandatoryProperties(CustomJDBCUserStoreManagerConstants.CUSTOM_UM_MANDATORY_PROPERTIES.toArray
                (new Property[CustomJDBCUserStoreManagerConstants.CUSTOM_UM_MANDATORY_PROPERTIES.size()]));
        properties.setOptionalProperties(CustomJDBCUserStoreManagerConstants.CUSTOM_UM_OPTIONAL_PROPERTIES.toArray
                (new Property[CustomJDBCUserStoreManagerConstants.CUSTOM_UM_OPTIONAL_PROPERTIES.size()]));
        properties.setAdvancedProperties(CustomJDBCUserStoreManagerConstants.CUSTOM_UM_ADVANCED_PROPERTIES.toArray
                (new Property[CustomJDBCUserStoreManagerConstants.CUSTOM_UM_ADVANCED_PROPERTIES.size()]));
        return properties;
    }


}
```

CustomJDBCUserStoreManagerConstants.java:

```
/*
 * Copyright 2005-2007 WSO2, Inc. (http://wso2.com)
 *
 * Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
 * you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
 * You may obtain a copy of the License at
 *
 * http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
 *
 * Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
 * distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
 * WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
 * See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
 * limitations under the License.
 */
package org.wso2.sample.user.store.manager;


import org.wso2.carbon.user.api.Property;
import org.wso2.carbon.user.core.UserStoreConfigConstants;
import org.wso2.carbon.user.core.jdbc.JDBCRealmConstants;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class CustomJDBCUserStoreManagerConstants {


    //Properties for Read Active Directory User Store Manager
    public static final ArrayList<Property> CUSTOM_UM_MANDATORY_PROPERTIES = new ArrayList<Property>();
    public static final ArrayList<Property> CUSTOM_UM_OPTIONAL_PROPERTIES = new ArrayList<Property>();
    public static final ArrayList<Property> CUSTOM_UM_ADVANCED_PROPERTIES = new ArrayList<Property>();

    static {
        setMandatoryProperty(JDBCRealmConstants.DRIVER_NAME, "", "Full qualified driver name");
        setMandatoryProperty(JDBCRealmConstants.URL, "", "URL of the user store database");
        setMandatoryProperty(JDBCRealmConstants.USER_NAME, "", "Username for the database");
        setMandatoryProperty(JDBCRealmConstants.PASSWORD, "", "Password for the database");

        setProperty(UserStoreConfigConstants.disabled, "false", UserStoreConfigConstants.disabledDescription);

        setProperty("ReadOnly", "true", "Indicates whether the user store of this realm operates in the user read only mode or not");
        setProperty(UserStoreConfigConstants.SCIMEnabled, "false", UserStoreConfigConstants.SCIMEnabledDescription);


        //Advanced Properties (No descriptions added for each property)
        setAdvancedProperty(JDBCRealmConstants.SELECT_USER, "SELECT * FROM WSO2_USER_MASTER WHERE USER_ID=?", "");
        setAdvancedProperty(JDBCRealmConstants.GET_USER_FILTER, "SELECT USER_ID FROM WSO2_USER_MASTER WHERE USER_ID LIKE ?  ORDER BY USER_ID", "");

    }

    private static void setProperty(String name, String value, String description) {
        Property property = new Property(name, value, description, null);
        CUSTOM_UM_OPTIONAL_PROPERTIES.add(property);

    }

    private static void setMandatoryProperty(String name, String value, String description) {
        Property property = new Property(name, value, description, null);
        CUSTOM_UM_MANDATORY_PROPERTIES.add(property);

    }

    private static void setAdvancedProperty(String name, String value, String description) {
        Property property = new Property(name, value, description, null);
        CUSTOM_UM_ADVANCED_PROPERTIES.add(property);

    }


}
```

CustomJDBCUserStoreMgtDSComponent:

```
package org.wso2.sample.user.store.manager.internal;

import org.apache.commons.logging.Log;
import org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory;
import org.osgi.service.component.ComponentContext;
import org.wso2.carbon.user.api.UserStoreManager;
import org.wso2.carbon.user.core.service.RealmService;
import org.wso2.sample.user.store.manager.CustomJDBCUserStoreManager;
import org.osgi.service.component.annotations.Activate;
import org.osgi.service.component.annotations.Component;
import org.osgi.service.component.annotations.Deactivate;
import org.osgi.service.component.annotations.Reference;
import org.osgi.service.component.annotations.ReferenceCardinality;
import org.osgi.service.component.annotations.ReferencePolicy;


@Component(
        name = "custom.authenticator.dscomponent",
        immediate = true

)
public class CustomJDBCUserStoreMgtDSComponent {
    private static Log log = LogFactory.getLog(CustomJDBCUserStoreMgtDSComponent.class);
    private static RealmService realmService;

    @Activate
    protected void activate(ComponentContext ctxt) {

        CustomJDBCUserStoreManager customUserStoreManager = new CustomJDBCUserStoreManager();
        ctxt.getBundleContext().registerService(UserStoreManager.class.getName(), customUserStoreManager, null);
        log.info("CustomUserStoreManager bundle activated successfully..");
    }

    @Deactivate
    protected void deactivate(ComponentContext ctxt) {
        if (log.isDebugEnabled()) {
            log.debug("Custom User Store Manager is deactivated ");
        }
    }

    @Reference(
            name = "RealmService",
            service = org.wso2.carbon.user.core.service.RealmService.class,
            cardinality = ReferenceCardinality.MANDATORY,
            policy = ReferencePolicy.DYNAMIC,
            unbind = "unsetRealmService")
    protected void setRealmService(RealmService rlmService) {
          realmService = rlmService;
    }

    protected void unsetRealmService(RealmService realmService) {
        realmService = null;
    }
}
```

Comment: Finally this code seems to work. Now I am getting my bundle activated and also in carbon screen I am able to see the custom user store manager in drop down. So I have added a new user store with the custom user store manager. I am able to see the users in carbon screen as red only but my authentication is getting failed.


Im getting this exception:
{
    "error_description": "Error while authenticating user from user store",
    "error": "invalid_grant"
}

Comment: @Buddhima Udaranga can you pls guide me on this??

Comment: Also I have added logs to chk the issue but its not getting printed in wso2carbon.log. BTW I have included the below line in log4j.properties:

log4j.logger.org.wso2.sample.user.store.manager.CustomJDBCUserStoreManager=INFO,WARN,ERROR,DEBUG

Answer (score 1):

The carbon kernel version that you have specified in the pom.xml file is not the version that is used in the Identity Server 5.7.0[1] use the version as 4.4.35.

Also, try replacing the ***instructions*** tag in the pom file by the following

```
               <instructions>
                    <Bundle-SymbolicName>${project.artifactId}</Bundle-SymbolicName>
                    <Bundle-Name>${project.artifactId}</Bundle-Name>
                    <Private-Package>
                        org.wso2.custom.user.store.internal
                    </Private-Package>
                    <Export-Package>
                        !org.wso2.custom.user.store.internal,
                        org.wso2.custom.user.store.*,
                    </Export-Package>
                 <DynamicImport-Package>*</DynamicImport-Package>
                </instructions>
```

Using the **DynamicImport-Package** is not recommended but it might help you to debug the issue.

[1]. https://github.com/wso2/product-is/blob/v5.7.0/pom.xml#L1859

Comment: I have tried changing the version to 4.4.35. But still the issue not resolved. Im still not seeing the activated logs. Is anything wrong with the code??

Comment: This code is compatible with is-5.0.0 there can be several issues in the code  You can use this one insted https://github.com/wso2/product-is/tree/master/modules/samples/user-mgt/sample-custom-user-store-manager